# using the Error using surf---X, Y, Z, and C cannot be complex

Tags: matlab

I have been trying to plot a spherical surface using the routine below but i get this error message "using the Error using surf (line 75)
X, Y, Z, and C cannot be complex" each time i try to run this code.
I need your opinions to solve this problem.
Thanks

Error in draw_sph (line 38)
surf(x,z,y,'facecolor','interp',...

```
     D=[50,0,0];
     c=1/10;
     k=1;
     Vertex=[0 0 0];


      M=5;
      n=2^(M-1);

      phi =(linspace(0,2*pi,n));
      r=(linspace(0,D(1),n))';

      x = r*cos(phi)+Vertex(1);
      y = r*sin(phi)+Vertex(2);
      z = (c*((r*cos(phi)).^2+(r*sin(phi)).^2))./
           (1+sqrt(1-(1+k)*c^2*((r*cos(phi)).^2+(r*sin(phi)).^2)))+Vertex(3);



     surf(x,z,y,'facecolor','interp',...
     'edgecolor','none',...
     'facelighting','phong'); 


     axis equal
     axis tight
     %camlight left
     alpha(.33)



     draw=1;
```

Comment: what is c? And can you post code that makes this exact error, because some of your code is missing.

Comment: Thanks. i have added a few more lines where i have defined these values

Comment: well, `z` ends up being imaginary... probably has something to do with that `sqrt`.

Answer (score 0):

```
sqrt(1-(1+k)*c^2*((r*cos(phi)).^2+(r*sin(phi)).^2))
```

can generate some complex value.

Equation is actualy

```
sqrt(1-(1+k)*c^2*(r^2))
```

If you take into account that sin^2 + cos^2 is 1. and r can be than pretty high...

Comment: I'm not sure this is quite right since `r` and `phi` are a column and row vector respectively.

Comment: isnt ((r*cos(phi)).^2+(r*sin(phi)).^2)) equal to r^2 ?

Comment: `r` is a vector. `r^2` doesn't even make sense

Comment: yeah ((r*cos(phi)).^2+(r*sin(phi)).^2))  is equal to r^2